# Serialport module in node.js works only if minicom is active on the port

Tags: node.js, serial-port, node-serialport

I am using version 3.10 of the serialport module of Node.js.
I have a GSM modem attached to an Ubuntu machine's serialport and I am sending SMS through the modem. Here is the simplified code:

```
var serialPort = require("serialport");
const Readline = serialPort.parsers.Readline;

var portSerial = new serialPort("/dev/ttyUSB1", {
    baudrate: 115200,
    dataBits:8, stopBits:1, parity: 'none'
}, function (err) {
    if (err)
      //log error here
    });

parser = new Readline();

portSerial.pipe(parser);

portSerial.on("open", function(err) {
  if (err)
     return console.log("Error in opening serial port");
  console.log("Port opened");
});

portSerial.on('error', function(err) {
   //log error
})

//Send SMS
setTimeout(function() {
  portSerial.write('AT+CMGF=1\nAT+CMGS="'+SMSphone + '"\n' +     
              SMSmessage +  '\032');
}, 1000);
```

Yes, I am setting SMSphone and SMSmessage variables.  And the code is actually a bit more complex but the core code for sending SMS is as shown above.

PROBLEM: All works fine if I am running minicom when the SMS is sent. The moment I exit minicom, the SMS do not go out.  portSerial.write stops working.

It was all working fine until I upgraded the serialport version.

Comment: I haven't used serialport in years so I cant really help. One question though: why do you use v3.10? and not the latest version v5.0 (https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport/releases/tag/5.0.0) -- That might fix your issues. You could also try the beta v6.0.

Comment: @ladislas Thanks a lot.  I installed using npm and it installed the 3.x version. I got the tar ball suggested by you but how do I install it? I did  a tar to untar it and I do see some files but not a single .js file! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @ladislas  Sorry... I had installed 5.00. It was the npm version that was 3.10. Just noticed!

Comment: then I don't really know. You should report the issue on Github, they might be able to help